# Use gnome-terminal as the Fzf launcher in GVim

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, gvim, xterm

How can you use **gnome-terminal** as the launcher of **fzf** in **GVim** instead of the default **xterm**:

https://github.com/junegunn/fzf

```
let g:fzf_launcher = 'xterm -e bash -ic %s'
```

I want to use **gnome-terminal** because it’s interface is more familiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determined by trial and error by adding and/or removing options:

```
let g:fzf_launcher='gnome-terminal --disable-factory -x bash -ic %s'
```

Comment: Unfortunately newer versions of gnome-terminal don't have --disable-factory so this no longer works.